# how to find frequency distribution in a data frame with respect to a particular column using pandas in python

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, frequency-distribution

I have a data-frame like this,

```
df,
A   B   C   D   Final
a   b   c   d   Valid
a       c       Valid
a       c   d   Valid
a               Valid
```

I want to calculate how many % of each column present in the Final Column.

My desired output is,

```
output = a=4,b=1,c=3,d=2
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If empty values are missing use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) with [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html):

```
print (df)
   A    B    C    D  Final
0  a    b    c    d  Valid
1  a  NaN    c  NaN  Valid
2  a  NaN    c    d  Valid
3  a  NaN  NaN  NaN  Valid

df = df.drop('Final', axis=1).count()
print (df)
A    4
B    1
C    3
D    2
dtype: int64
```

If values are empty strings first compare by [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and `sum` `True`s:

```
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  Final
0  a  b  c  d  Valid
1  a     c     Valid
2  a     c  d  Valid
3  a           Valid

df = df.drop('Final', axis=1).ne('').sum()
print (df)
A    4
B    1
C    3
D    2
dtype: int64
```

---

```
print (df.to_dict())
{'B': 1, 'A': 4, 'C': 3, 'D': 2}

d = df.div(len(df.index)).mul(100).to_dict()
print (d)
{'B': 25.0, 'A': 100.0, 'C': 75.0, 'D': 50.0}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the column names and values in a dictionary like A:4,B:1,C:3,D:2

Comment: Sure, last add `to_dict()`

Comment: actually im trying get the % of each column with respect to Final column,
l want like A:100,B:25,C:75,D:50

Comment: So what is desired output?

Comment: What about `d = df.drop('Final', 1).ne('').sum().div(len(df.index)).to_dict()`
    `print (d)`
    `{'B': 0.25, 'A': 1.0, 'C': 0.75, 'D': 0.5}` ?

Comment: l want like A:100,B:25,C:75,D:50

Comment: I add it to answer. I think better is float output, because if divide real data integer outputs get very rarely, obviolusly get floats.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155297/discussion-between-pyd-and-jezrael).